# Find the minimum polynomial of $u$ over $Q$ where $u=\sqrt3-(1+(5/2)^{1/3})^{1/4}$

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field, minimal-polynomials

I tried using the binomial theorem but the terms keep increasing indefinitely

Comment: Minimal polynomial of $\mathbb Q(u)$? Don't you mean of $u$? Over $\mathbb Q$?

Comment: [WA](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=minimum+polynomial+of+%5Csqrt3-(1%2B(5%2F2)%5E(1%2F3))%5E(1%2F4)) says that it's $4 x^{24}-144 x^{22}+2352 x^{20}-23616 x^{18}+164544 x^{16}-836352 x^{14}+3158252 x^{12}-8842104 x^{10}+17630256 x^8-24529248 x^6+17716992 x^4-7354368 x^2+1038361$.

Comment: I edited, thanks

Comment: @lhf, its an exercise in my textbook, do they expect me to work that out by hand?

Comment: @Adoedatus, I don't know. Which book is it?

Answer (score 2):

Find a polynomial that $v=u-\sqrt{3}$ satisfies.  It is degree $12$.
Substitute in so it is now $p(u)+\sqrt{3}q(u)=0$.
Try to find a polynomial, involving $p(u),q(u)$ and integer coefficients.  lhf tells you it is degree-24.

Comment: Thanks alot, this really helps. (quiet easy, i didnt think of that)